# not finding codenarc ruleset using build.gradle

Tags: gradle, codenarc

Trying to apply codenarc to a spring boot project, however the gradle build is producing :codenarcMain NO-SOURCE. Please advise on what I am doing wrong.

1) Added plugins to build.gradle

`apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'codenarc'`

2) Then added the following to the build.gradle

```
codenarc {
    ignoreFailures = true
  }

codenarcMain {
    reports {
        html.enabled = true
    }
    configFile = file("$rootDir/config/codenarc/rules.groovy")
  }
```

3) created rules definition in the file rules.groovy

`$rootDir/config/codenarc/rules.groovy`